# failsafe wget html script? (when user uses ~\.wgetrc)

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I just ran into an issue. It was about a code snippet from one of alienbob's script that he uses to check the most recent Adobeflash version on adobe.com:

```
# Determine the latest version by checking the web page:
VERSION=${VERSION:-"$(wget -O - http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ 2>/dev/null | sed -n "/Firefox - NPAPI/{N;p}" | tr -d ' '| tail -1 | tr '<>' '  ' | cut -f3 -d ' ')"}
echo "Latest version = "$VERSION
```

That code, in itself usually works like a charm, but not for me. I use a custom `~\.wgetrc`, cause I ran into issues with some pages that disallowed wget to make even a single download. Usually I make no mass downloads on any site, unless the sites allows such things, or I set a reasonable pause in my wget script one one-liner.

Now, among other things, the `~\.wgetrc` setup masks my wget as a Windows Firefox, and also includes this line:

```
header = Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

And that means, when I use wget to download a html file, it downloads that file as gipped html.

Now I wonder, is there a trick to still make a script like the alienbob one work on such a user setup, or did the user mess up his own system with that setup and has to figure out by himself why the script malfunctions?

(In my case, I could just remove the `header = Accept-Encoding` line, and all works as it should, since when using wget, one usually not wants html files to be gzipped)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
wget --header=Accept-Encoding:identity -O - ....
```

as the header option will take precedence over .wgetrc option of the same name.

Maybe the target page was redesigned, this is the wget part which works for me now:

```
wget --header=Accept-Encoding:identity -O - http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ 2>/dev/null | fgrep -m 1 -A 2 "Firefox - NPAPI" | tail -1 | sed s/\</\>/g | cut -d\> -f3
```